# Ruby On Rails: How to keep has_one relation and another has_one as a separate name/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

What I want to achieve is an apprenticeship relationship with a simple setup as following

```
class Apprentice
   attr_accessible :apprentice, :mentor, :other_details
   has_one :employee #contains the apprentice information
   has_one :employee #contains the mentor information
end
class Employee
   attr_accessible :name, :age, :gender
end
```

How can I make employee to be both an apprentice and a mentor in the apprentice object? In addition, I have made Employee polymorphic since I have other objects that need to use it.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for editing my notes. How did you make all the spaces without html?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :mentor, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'mentor_id'
  has_one :apprentice, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'apprentice_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what would best suit the problem you've described is a self-referential relationship, where "an employee has a mentor". Your models could look like this:

```
# id - PK of the employee
# name - Name of the employee
# age - Age of the employee
# gender - Gender of the employee
# mentor_id - The employee's mentor
class Employee
  belongs_to :mentor, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

This way, you could find all of the apprentices by searching for employees where `mentor` is `nil`, and you could find all of the mentors by searching for employees where `mentor` is not `nil`.

Comment: Thank. Employee has a polymorphic belongs_to relationship to a bunch of other objects. Can I still make it self-referential then without losing the polymorphic?

Comment: This will work with any other kind of relationship you want to add to `Employee`. If you are not familiar with schema design (foreign keys), I'd recommend researching a bit about it so that you know what exactly is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Sounds good. I will definitely try self-referential relationships in the future. Any sources where I can dig deeper? And currently I am using  has_one :apprentice, class_name: 'Employee', conditions: "role = 'apprentice'", as: :polymorphic. This seems to work fine for now. Any ideas?

Comment: There are several ways to approach generating associations in Ruby on Rails, so as long as your solution is working you should be good. For digging deeper into this kind of thing, I would really recommend any beginner SQL course. A Google query should net you quite a few of those.